# How to name similar methods in different levels?

Tags: c++, naming

For example, I have two methods CreateNewDocument and OpenDocument, which are in two different levels in my GUI code. One is a low level, which just does what the method name means; the other is a high level, which will check possible unsavings of existing document before doing the required work. The low-level names appear in the high level code since they are called to implement the high level methods. My question is how to distinguish them in order not to obfuscate users and readers? Below please fine the illustrated code.

```
class GuiClass
{
public:
    // Re-implement to tell me how to do the low-level create new document.
    virtual void LowLevelCreateNewDocument(); 

    // Then I do the high-level version for you.
    void HighLevelCreateNewDocument()
    {
        // Handle unsavings and blabla...
        ...
        // Then do the low-level version
        LowLevelCreateNewDocument();
        // Afterward operations
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: `CreateNewDocument` and `OpenDocument` seem like two very different things to me. Both of which I'd consider high level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make that 'lower-level' `CreateNewDocument()`method `protected` or `private`, since it seems, that it should only be called from other class members within that class or derived ones respectively.

```
class GuiClass
{
public:
    // Then I do the high-level version for you.
    void CreateNewDocument()
    {
        // Handle unsavings and blabla...
        ...
        // Then do the low-level version
        CreateNewDocumentInternal();
    }

protected:
    //pure virtual to enforce implementation within derived classes.
    //                                        |
    //                                        V
    virtual void CreateNewDocumentInternal() = 0; 
};

class GuiClassImpl : public GuiClass
{
protected:
    /*virtual*/ void CreateNewDocumentInternal()
    {
        //Do the low-level stuff here
    }
};
```

If these methods are really on different implementation levels, consider to put them into different classes or namespaces, as already suggested. With a subclass, which has to implement the pure virtual, protected member function, you already have appropriate encapsulation.